# Explicit GC while collecting android device usage data using adb commands

Tags: android, performance, garbage-collection, adb

When I use adb commands to collect memory, cpu, network data from the device i get frequent Explicit GC operations.

I/art(29126): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 17MB/25MB, paused 559us total 19.188ms

How can i avoid it? It interrupts the data collection and app's operations.
why does it called on behalf of the app (in the logs). I am calling the commands through adb?

Answer (score 0):

It is not being called on the application's behalf - if it were, it's logtag would be the same as the application's instead of `aart` or `dalvikvm` :) Perhaps the app is just freeing up some of it's resources due to you forcing a GC cycle explicitly.

Comment: I will be more specific. when i use "adb shell dumpsys meminfo <package-name> i get theses explicit GC logs. the tag is "art" but the application is mine. i dont use explicit GC just this command.